# Can't get page's email using Graph Api

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I'm using explorer to test this request "`::page_id::?fields=id,name,emails`", but it returns this error message:

```
{
  "error": {
    "message": "(#100) Tried accessing nonexisting field (emails) on node type (PlaceInformation)",
    "type": "OAuthException",
    "code": 100,
    "fbtrace_id": "Hzq4cKMXlI1"
  }
}
```

I already tried to use contact_email and user_support_email, but it also didn't work.

What is the right field to get page email?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a close look at the error message, it says `node type (PlaceInformation)`. I assume you are trying to use a Place, not a Page. Those are the fields available for Places: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/place/

Comment: How could I change my request to uso Page? I thought I was already requesting to it

Comment: how did you get the page id?

Comment: I guest that was the problem, I search for the place and use "id" as if it was page id but it was actually place id. When I try to use the id in app_links.android.url it gives me that answer: {
  "error": {
    "message": "(#10) To use 'Page Public Content Access', your use of this endpoint must be reviewed and approved by Facebook. To submit this 'Page Public Content Access' feature for review please read our documentation on reviewable features: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review.",
    "type": "OAuthException",
    "code": 10,
    "fbtrace_id": "DaNRxWsoSqN"
  }
}

Comment: How could I get the page id in a simple way? Do I really need to be approve by facebook to get the email?

Comment: you must get page public content access approved for any access to pages you don´t own. if it is your own page, just use a page token of that page.

Comment: Thanks for all the help